# How to know that the wordpress post type is visual or text?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress gives two options while creating a post.

- one is visual
- another is text

[image]

How to know in php code that the post is of visual or text type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confused about what those tabs do. They simply toggle between the exact same data. One tab rendered the exact markup you have created, and the other one renders that (same!) markup PLUS the CSS file that is associated with the editor.

There is no way to tell them apart, since they are (literally) the same thing.

Comment: I want to apply a filter to my post content if the post is created by using the text type and not visual type . How can i do that . Any idea @mayersdesign

Comment: Hi. No I really don't think it is possible. I don't believe there is a way to tell. Even if there was it would be something mad like "what tab was last selected when the post was saved". It's simply irrelevant. Both tabs show the same thing. I am trying to think of a metaphor. Maybe... "How many fingers am I holding up if you look through your left eye, or your right?" -  It's the same :)

Comment: @selftaught91 - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes I got the concept